# Update last character of string with a value

Tags: python

I have two strings:

```
input = "12.34.45.362"
output = "2"
```

I want to be able to replace the `362` in input by `2` from output.

Thus the final result should be `12.34.45.2`. I am unsure on how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This post shows zero effort or research on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex for this:

```
import re

input_ = "12.34.45.362"
output = "2"

input_ = re.sub(r"\.\d+$", f".{output}", input_)
print(input_)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 12.34.45.2
> ```

Notice that I also changed `input` to `input_`, so we're not shadowing the built-in [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function.

Can also use a more simple, but little bit less robust pattern, which doesn't take the period into account at all, and just replaces all the digits from the end:

```
import re

input_ = "12.34.45.362"
output = "2"

input_ = re.sub(r"\d+$", output, input_)
print(input_)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 12.34.45.2
> ```

Comment: The last number after the ```.``` could be varying in size so assuming -3 wont always work. Do you know a better way?

Comment: I just had a quick question, if wanted to get the ```362``` of the input_1, would using a slipt operation be efficient? Something like this. ```input_.rsplit(".",1)[-1]```

Comment: @LauraSmith Pretty much no point in worrying about efficience in these kinds of operations, but the easiest way would probably be: `input_.split(".")[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to do this for any string of form `X.Y.Z.W` where `X`, `Y`, `Z`, and `W` may be of non-constant length:

```py
new_result = ".".join(your_input.split(".")[:-1]) + "." + output
```

`s.join` will join a collection together to a string using the string `s` between each element. `s.split` will turn a string into a `list` which each element between the given character `.`. Slicing the list (`l[:-1]`) will give you all but the last element, and finally string concatenation (if you are sure `output` is `str`) will give you your result.

Breaking it down step-by-step:

```py
your_input = "12.34.45.362"
your_input.split(".")  # == ["12", "34", "45", "362"]
your_input.split(".")[:-1]  # == ["12", "34", "45"]
".".join(your_input.split(".")[:-1])  # == "12.34.45"
".".join(your_input.split(".")[:-1]) + "." + output  # == "12.34.45.2"
```

Comment: Did you test it on the inputs given above? I tried it and it doesnt work

Comment: Forgot two full-stop characters which have been amended.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to split int the lat `.` just do a right split get everything and do a string formatting

```
i = "12.34.45.362"
r = "{}.2".format(i.rsplit(".",1)[0])
```

output

```
'12.34.45.2'
```